# AWS AutoScaling Not Scaling Up

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I've setup an AWS AutoScaling group. Have 2 alarms to increase the number of servers if the average load is above 65% and decrease if it's less than 35%. Not sure what the final numbers will be, but this is what I initially used. I ran a `yes >& /dev/null` command on the linux server and the load very quickly went up to 100% (as reported by linux `top` command), but no new instances were being launched, because I think the alarms were not triggering. How exactly is the cpu load average computed/retrieved by the Auto Scaler?

I also, as an experiment, killed responding to the AWS ping commands from the server and thus, it was deemed not healthy by the AWS. The server was terminated and a new one was started up. So, I know that launching/terminating of servers is working in the Auto Scaler due to "health" reason.

- What else should I look at to diagnose the problem?
- Is my way of stressing the server not the "right" way as far as the Auto Scaler is concerned?
- Is it using a different benchmark?

Comment: please add more details on your alarm settings. does "yes >& /dev/null" load whole cpu?

Comment: I am using t1.micro instance, which only has 1 cpu, the load, as reported by the linux "top" command, is at 100%. The alarm is setup to increase the instances by 1, when the load is >= 65%. How does AutoScaler determine the actual instance load?

Comment: alarm has threshold and amount of periods this threshold is crossed to fire. there are handy graphs in cloudwatch console that should help you understand what is going on

Answer (score 0):

[This is a comment not an answer]

You can use [set-alarm-state](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/set-alarm-state.html) in aws cli to trigger your alarms

```
aws cloudwatch set-alarm-state --alarm-name "myalarm" --state-value ALARM --state-reason "testing purposes"
```

This way you can easily test them out. If you still have problems then maybe you can post the output of

```
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --alarm-names "myalarm"
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Your Average load from both the instances should cross 65% only then a new instance is launched. So, in your case the load on both the instances must cross 65%. Only then AutoScaling Group launches a new instance.

You can use tools such as BeesWithMachineGuns, Loadrunner and other Load testing tools to increase load of your server such that it goes above 65%.

**Suggestion:** Check your server load on Cloudwatch metrics rather than from inside the server( using top). This will give you a clear picture of how AWS is calculating your Instance load.